# Tradução na caixa de sinalização

Tags: bug, tradução

Ao rever a sinalização já feita para [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197548/loop-pivot-tables-accourding-to-the-contries-in-the-database) em outro idioma, me deparei com um texto ainda não traduzido.

[image: tradução]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugeri uma tradução como

> Você já fez uma sinalização de fechamento.

Agora falta os revisores aprovarem e aí esperar o próximo build.

Comment: Muito bom jbueno, obrigado!

Comment: Foram todas pro ar, já.